# How to find how many values are divisible in to certain value in 2d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, random

The following code generate random number of 2d arrays and I want to print how many values in each pair are divisible to 3. For example assume we have an array [[2, 10], [1, 6], [4, 8]].
So the first pair which is [2,10] has 3 ,6 and 9 which are totally 3 and second pair has 3 and 6 which are totally two and last pair[4,8] has just 1 divisible to 3 which is 6. Therefore, The final out put should print sum of total number of divisible values which is 3+2+1=6

```
a=random.randint(1, 10)

b = np.random.randint(1,10,(a,2))
b = [sorted(i) for i in b]   
c = np.array(b)            
   
counter = 0;   
  
for i in range(len(c)): 
    d=(c[i,0],c[i,1])
    if (i % 3 == 0):  
        counter = counter + 1
print(counter)
```

Comment: Do you mean `[2, 10]`, `[1, 6]`, and `[4, 8]` are [intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)) and you want to calculate how many integers in each interval are divisible by 3?

Comment: Yes. That is right

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `sum()` builtin for the task:

```
l = [[2, 10], [1, 6], [4, 8]]

print( sum(v % 3 == 0 for a, b in l for v in range(a, b+1)) )
```

Prints:

```
6
```

---

EDIT: To count number of perfect squares:

```
def is_square(n):
    return (n**.5).is_integer()

print( sum(is_square(v) for a, b in l for v in range(a, b+1)) )
```

Prints:

```
5
```

---

EDIT 2: To print info about each interval, just combine the two examples above. For example:

```
def is_square(n):
    return (n**.5).is_integer()

for a, b in l:
    print('Pair {},{}:'.format(a, b))
    print('Number of divisible 3: {}'.format(sum(v % 3 == 0 for v in range(a, b+1))))
    print('Number squares: {}'.format(sum(is_square(v) for v in range(a, b+1))))
    print()
```

Prints:

```
Pair 2,10:
Number of divisible 3: 3
Number squares: 2

Pair 1,6:
Number of divisible 3: 2
Number squares: 2

Pair 4,8:
Number of divisible 3: 1
Number squares: 1
```

Comment: Thanks, and how we can find total number of values that have a perfect square within all pairs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. what if I want to print number of divisible and perfect square of each pair without summing them. for example for first pair print 3 2 which 3 is number of divisible and 2 is number of perfect square.

Comment: This is exactly why code-only answers are not helpful to beginners. Teach a man to fish and whatnot.

Comment: @user14263018 See my EDIT2.

Comment: Thanks.I am trying to use for a, b in c:    
    print('{}'.format(sum(v % 3 == 0, is_square(v) for v in range(a, b+1)))) for number of values in the pairs have both criteria (divisible and perfect square) and it's not working

Comment: @user14263018 You probably meant `print('{}'.format(sum((v % 3 == 0) and is_square(v) for v in range(a, b+1))))` that will print number of numbers which are perfect squares AND divisible by 3.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to count how many integers in the interval are divisible by 3 by testing each one.

Another way, and this is much more efficient if your intervals are huge, is to use math.

Take the interval `[2, 10]`.

`2 / 3 = 0.66; ceil(2 / 3) = 1`.

`10 / 3 = 3.33; floor(10 / 3) = 3`.

Now we need to count how many integers exist between 0.66 and 3.33, or count how many integers exist between 1 and 3. Hey, that sounds an awful lot like subtraction! (and then adding one)

Let's write this as a function

```
from math import floor, ceil
def numdiv(x, y, div):
    return floor(y / div) - ceil(x / div) + 1
```

So given a list of intervals, we can call it like so:

```
count = 0
intervals = [[2, 10], [1, 6], [4, 8]]
for interval in intervals:
    count += numdiv(interval[0], interval[1], 3)
print(count)
```

Or using a list comprehension and sum:

```
count = sum([numdiv(interval[0], interval[1], 3) for interval in intervals])
```